# A question on physical locations of the registers in ATmega328P

Tags: atmega328, avr

When I read about registers I always encounter the following illustration:

[image]

So there are 32 registers in the above diagram. They are processor registers.

But in the [data-sheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) of ATmega328P at page 428 there is a section called "Register Summary".

Here in that list there are much more than 32 registers. Do the rest of the registers physically stay somewhere else?

Lest's take an example of ADMUX register. Where is that register physically inside the DIP? It is not one of the 32 registers? And if stays somewhere else how does it connected to the ALU?

Comment: Physical location or memory location? The datasheetss has the later.

Comment: I mean is ADMUX one of those 32 reg?

Comment: In the table that you refer to, ADMUX is mapped to memory location 0x7C.

Comment: No, R0 to R31 are General Purpose registers for use in your application. The compiler usually takes care of using them appropriately. All the other registers are special purpose and can only be utilised explicitly. Those registers form the state machine of the MCU.

Comment: Is GPIO a subset of SFR?

Comment: And are they all SFT and 32 tegistrts all inside sram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing CPU registers and SFRs, Special Function Registers.

CPU registers only exist within the CPU core. SFRs exist within the RAM bus's memory map.

CPU registers are used by the CPU to execute instructions and do calculations, etc. SFRs are a part of the logic of the rest of the chip and directly affect the working of the various peripherals.

As far as the CPU is concerned an SFR is just a bit of SRAM, but it affects physical workings when written to, and reflects physical states when read from.

Comment: Chapter 8.3 in the ATMEGA328P datasheet (ver 10/2014) has a memory map of SRAM. Here it uses the term IO Register and Extended IO Register to refer to the Special Function Registers.

Comment: Every manufacturer has their own name for them. SFR is an accepted standard name for the concept.

Comment: Are those 32 registers called GPIO?

Comment: No. They are called registers. They are the internal memory of the CPU. You have very limited access to them in C, but in assembly they are all you have for doing any form of calculations with.

Comment: Some wrote under my question that they re called general purpose registers. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, since the CPU can use them for any purpose it needs. Really, unless you are writing assembly language programs, you don't even need to know about the existence of these 32 registers. They are like the spark plugs in your car - you don't need to know about them to be able to drive it.